# Critical points for multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Suppose you have the function, $$\space f(x,y) =5xy(9-x-y)$$ and you have to find the critical points of $\space f(x,y)$. To start, I found the $f_x$ and $f_y$ and set each to $0$. Then, I tried to solve the system of equations:

$$f_{x} = -5y^2-10xy+45y = 0$$ $$f_y = -5x^2-10xy+45x = 0$$

At this point, is there a simple method to solve this system? I am thinking I should multiply $\space f_y$ by $-1$, yielding: $$-5y^2-10xy+45y = 0$$ $$5x^2+10xy-45x = 0$$ and then adding the equations together, but I don't think that is useful. Additionally, I think I can solve the top equation for $x$ and then plug the resulting equation into $f_y$, but that is tedious.

Thanks!

Comment: $$(x=0\land y=9)\lor (x=3\land y=3)\lor (x=9\land y=0)\lor (y=0\land x=0)$$

Comment: @Moo Oh! How did you do that?

Comment: Solve the first equation for $x$ and substitute into the second. That gives you a quadratic equation.

Comment: @Moo Ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is useful because it gives you the equation
(after cancelling 5)
$$
x^2-y^2-9(x-y)=0.
$$
Now use $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ to factor out $x-y$
$$
(x-y)(x+y-9)=0.
$$